# Awaiting a void function in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await

Hi I was wondering how I could await a void function.
I tried the following (mock up):

```js
async function asyncer() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("async msg")
  }, 0)
}

async function helloer() {
  await asyncer()
  console.log("hello")
}

helloer()
```

This however doesn't work, so I tried the following :

```js
async function asyncer() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("async msg")
  }, 0)
  return true
}

async function helloer() {
  let ready = await asyncer()
  if (ready) {
    console.log("hello")
  }
}

helloer()
```

Still "hello" is still logged before "async msg".
Does anyone know a solution to this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `Promise` see here for more detail https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: setTimeout doesn't block. `await` is for promises, of which there are none here. Please check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async/await is a syntax sugar for promise.then, so create a Promise.resolve or smth to enter in async flow and then use async/await